# I want to implement Alarm in my app with respect to spinner

Tags: android, spinner, alarmmanager

I have defined spinner as

```
 List<String> categories = new ArrayList<String>();

    categories.add("5 minutes before ETA");
    categories.add("10 minutes before ETA");
    categories.add("15 minutes before ETA");
    categories.add("20 minutes before ETA");
    categories.add("25 minutes before ETA");
    categories.add("30 minutes before ETA");
    categories.add("1 hours before ETA");
    categories.add("2 hours before ETA");
```

When first item on spinner is clicked.Alarm should start before 5 minute and respectively for other items details.I want logic to start alarm in context with spinner list mentioned.

Comment: So what is the Question  ?

Comment: You could use AlarmManager for this: http://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html

Comment: I want to set alarm according to spinner list item. when first item is clicked alarm should starts before 5 minutes and when second item is clicked alarm should start before 10 minutes